# MyApp stop working on actual Device

Tags: android

My app works great in virtual device but when i run it on actual device i got " **my app stopped working**" error .. and this error in the log

```
06-07 12:20:09.022 28371-28371/my.amirul.psm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException at     my.amirul.psm.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:113)
at my.amirul.psm.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:22)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my code for the background task...

```
 public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

AlertDialog alertDialog;
Context ctx;
BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
{
this.ctx = ctx;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information......");
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String reg_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/register.php";
    String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2/webapp/login.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if(method.equals("register"))
    {
    String name = params[1];
    String user_name = params[2];
    String user_pass = params [3];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("user_pass","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass,"UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();
            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            return "Registration Success...";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (method.equals("login"))
    {
       String login_name = params[1];
        String login_pass = params[2];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
      String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
              URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
              response+= line ;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (result.equals("Registration Success...")) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if(result.contains("Hello")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, FormActivity.class);
        ctx.startActivity(i);
    } else {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
}
```

plz help me ...

Comment: Please post your code to find out the issue ...

Comment: Are you using same version in Emulator and real device?

Comment: @CoolJavaguy yes im using api 17 as my minimum sdk

Comment: @AbdulMomenKhan check edit

Comment: If you want to run this code means kindly change your 10.0.2.2 address to system ip address

Comment: @SathishKumarJ im sorry but i dont understand.. how can i change it?

Comment: Is your phone connected to same wifi network?

Comment: @CoolJavaguy no... i didnt connect my phone to any network

Comment: Please connect your phone with wifi and then try it.

Comment: @CoolJavaguy do u meant i need to hv the same ip address on my phone with my laptop? sry im really bad at this .. plz help me T_T

Comment: connect your phone with wifi, thats it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the network is not available and the system received null when connect with network. On the emulator you are using network of your system. I hope it will help you.

Comment: You should check, whether network is available or not?

Comment: i connected my phone with a wifi connection other than the one connected to my laptop... now the app can not proceed to the next activity after log in activity

Comment: Dear you need same network because your php app is on this network. Connect with the same wifi router.

Comment: i can run the app now .. thankss ^_^Y... but still hv the same problem...  now the app can not proceed to the next activity after log in activity  and the input in register activity were not stored in the database

Comment: If it works for you, please select my answer and vote me up ;)

Comment: Your problem was exception that is resolve now. For next step please debug your app on device. You come to know what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device into Network either WiFi/Data Connection. and then

Assuming that you're on the same wireless network...

Find your local IP ADDRESS (should be something **192.168.1.x**) - go to the command prompt and type 'ipconfig' to get this. where x is the assigned local ip of the server machine.
use your local IP ADDRESS for your android device to connect to your localhost.

it worked for me.

> **Note :** To access localhost on emulator: 10.0.2.2. However this may not always work for example if you have something other than a web server such as XMPP server.

This may helps you.

Comment: soo i hv to replace 10.0.2.2 with my laptop's ip address?

Comment: i already change it to my laptop ip adress but it is still not fucntioning 100%

Answer (score 0):

Am I the only one to see the

```
return null;
```

out of every if/else statements at the end of doInBackground?

If there is a success, that's ok, because there is a `return "Registration Success...";` in the first if statement, but if it fails, it will be null, hence the null pointer exception.

Comment: Amirul: look at the last line of 'doInBackground'. It is 'return null;'. There is another return in the first if statement. So if there is a succes, it returns "Registration success", otherwise, it will go straight to  'return null;'. Therefore, if it fails (and it because of the IP problem), there will be a null pointer exception. At least, the last return should be initiated to a default value, not a null value.

Comment: should i change it? sryy but im not so good at this . haha just started a few weeks T_T

Comment: you can assign it a default value, or make sure all you if/else/try/catch statements return a valid result.